# Does Datical (Enterprise version of liquibase) support more than 2000 tables generateChangeLog?

Tags: database, liquibase

I have more than 2000 tables in my existing database.
I want generateChangeLog for all tables with structure and data.
I have tried using liquibase command but it is failed for all tables.
Is it possible in datical (Enterprise version of liquibase) with GUI or command ?

Liquibase command:

**liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --classpath=mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.0.8-bin.jar --changeLogFile=D:\newLiquibse\xml\XYZ.xml 
--url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:4928/MyDBName?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" --username=XYZ --password=XYZ --diffTypes="tables, columns, views, primaryKeys, indexes, foreignKeys, sequences, data" generateChangeLog**

I am using **Liquibase 3.3.5** version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Liquibase did not "just fail" - what was the error message you got? Which DBMS are you using? How did you generate the changelog (what was the exact command line you used)? Which Liquibase version are you using? Which JDBC driver version are you using?

Comment: Datical will not work any differently in this situation. I would further suggest that using Liquibase to migrate both structure AND data is probably not advised - Liquibase is really about migrating structure.

Comment: @SteveDonie, I took only structure of my all tables, Now generateChangeLog was successfully executed. But when I am going for data I am getting below error,                                                           com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown. And Unexpected error running Liquibase: GC overhead limit exceeded.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I am going for data"? I.e. what command did you give? Also, as I said before, using Liquibase to migrate data is not advised. You should look for other tools if you want to migrate the data.